# Getting gameobject from RaycastHit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this code but unfortunately i am getting this error:

> CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.RaycastHit' does not contain a definition for`gameObject' and no extension method `gameObject' of type`UnityEngine.RaycastHit' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
public float Selected;
public GameObject[] handler;
public float[] prices;
public GameObject Tile;
private Money mon;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mon =   GameObject.Find ("Gamelogic").GetComponent<Money>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast (ray,out hit, 20))
    {
        if(hit.transform.tag == "tiles")
        {
            Tile = hit.gameObject;
        }
        else 
        {
            Tile = null;
        }

    }
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Tile != null)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear: in the line `Tile = hit.gameObject`, the type of the `hit` object (`RaycastHit`) does not contain a field, property or method named `gameObject`. Please check the documentation to see the available public members of the class.

Comment: i checked it man but there is nothing i could find on this thing.

Comment: I think you need `hit.transform.gameObject` instead of `hit.gameObject`.

Comment: Btw, here is almost the same question: [http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/141529/getting-gameobject-from-raycast-hit.html](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/141529/getting-gameobject-from-raycast-hit.html)

Comment: @FalconUA you are a champ man

Answer (score 3):

Heres a function that I use, you should be able to adapt it easily.

```
GameObject GetClickedGameObject() 
{ 
    // Builds a ray from camera point of view to the mouse position 
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    RaycastHit hit; 
    // Casts the ray and get the first game object hit 
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask)) 
    {

        Instantiate (clickMarker,hit.point,Quaternion.identity); //places clickMarker at hit.point. This isn't needed, just there for visualisation. 
        return hit.transform.gameObject;
    }
    else 
        return null; 
}
```

I think your basic problem is that

```
Tile = hit.gameObject;
```

needs to be

```
Tile = hit.transform.gameObject;
```

Also:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
```

Pay attention to this way of doing it, it has a built in layerMask, so you dont need to do your if(hit.transform.tag == "tiles")

Answer (score 0):

Easier and shorter, you can always just do:

```
hit.collider.gameObject.name
```

which will return the nametag of the object you hit.
Then you can do logic checks and whatever you want to do with that info.

More docs here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/getting-object-hit-with-raycast.573982/